Excel Formula for Accrued Income over Promotion Period
My workbook has columns from Y:CD with dates
Included in the rows beneath this is customer revenue data
Contract end date is in S2 promotion start date is in t2 and promotion end date is in u2 cease date is in v2
Monthly sales price is in w2
I need a formula which will accrue the income cumulatively each month between the promotion start and end date and then in the columns once the promotion end date is reached, reduce the accumulated balance equally each month until the contract end date. If the column dates are outside of the promotion start date and contract end date it should return 0.
This date has a range of start and end dates with customers on different lengths of promotions
Mock File
I currently am using this formula
=IF(AM$5>=$T6,IF(AM$5<=$U6,IF(AM$5>$S6,0,(-$Z6*(DATEDIF($T6,AM$5,"m")+1))),IF(AM$5>$S6,0,($Z6*(DATEDIF($T6,$U6,"m")+1))/(DATEDIF($U6,$S6,"m")))),0)
however instead of row 6 showing -28.45, -56.90, -85.35, 5.42, 5.42 etc I need it to show calculation as
NEW with the unwind ending when the calculation reaches 0 at the contract end date

Welcome to SuperUser. Please share at least a mockup or sample of your data. Note that this site is not a script writing service, so also please show the research that you have done and what you have tried.

Your lack of punctuation makes it difficult to interpret your problem description. Please use markdown rather than images to show your tables: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#google_vignette
